# MSAL - Failed to set item into keychain when trying to authenticate Microsoft Graph login

Tags: ios, xcode, microsoft-graph-api, keychain, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to integrate with Microsoft Graph in my iOS application. I am developing in Swift on XCode. I followed this tutorial:

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-ios#register-your-application*

When I click connect, enter my login details, It keeps giving me the error message below. I have tried debugging and it goes into the acquireTokenInteractively() and the error is printed.

[image]
I have registered my application on the Microsoft app portal, enabled keychain sharing on the capabilities tab of the application etc, not really sure why this won't work..
thanks for any help.

```
import UIKit
import MSAL

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {

    // Update the below to your client ID you received in the portal. The below is for running the demo only
    let kClientID = "a88969f1-61c7-4322-a9a0-9212bb96b782"

    // These settings you don't need to edit unless you wish to attempt deeper scenarios with the app.
    let kGraphURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"
    //let kScopes: [String] = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"]
    let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"

    var accessToken = String()
    var applicationContext : MSALPublicClientApplication?

    @IBOutlet weak var connectButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signoutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var loggingText: UITextView!

    @IBAction func connectButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Connect button tapped")
        if self.currentAccount() == nil {
            // We check to see if we have a current logged in account.
            // If we don't, then we need to sign someone in.
            self.acquireTokenInteractively()
        } else {
            self.acquireTokenSilently()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func signoutButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Signout button tapped")
        guard let applicationContext = self.applicationContext else { return }

        guard let account = self.currentAccount() else { return }

        do {

            /**
             Removes all tokens from the cache for this application for the provided account
             - account:    The account to remove from the cache
             */

            try applicationContext.remove(account)
            self.loggingText.text = ""
            self.signoutButton.isEnabled = false

        } catch let error as NSError {

            self.loggingText.text = "Received error signing account out: \(error)"
        }
    }

    /**
     Setup public client application in viewDidLoad
     */

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {

            /**
             Initialize a MSALPublicClientApplication with a given clientID and authority
             - clientId:            The clientID of your application, you should get this from the app portal.
             - authority:           A URL indicating a directory that MSAL can use to obtain tokens. In Azure AD
             it is of the form https://<instance/<tenant>, where <instance> is the
             directory host (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com) and <tenant> is a
             identifier within the directory itself (e.g. a domain associated to the
             tenant, such as contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or the GUID representing the
             TenantID property of the directory)
             - error                The error that occurred creating the application object, if any, if you're
             not interested in the specific error pass in nil.
             */

            guard let authorityURL = URL(string: kAuthority) else {
                self.loggingText.text = "Unable to create authority URL"
                return
            }

            let authority = try MSALAuthority(url: authorityURL)
            self.applicationContext = try MSALPublicClientApplication(clientId: kClientID, authority: authority)

        } catch let error {
            self.loggingText.text = "Unable to create Application Context \(error)"
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        signoutButton.isEnabled = !self.accessToken.isEmpty
    }

    /**
     This button will invoke the authorization flow.
     */

    @IBAction func callGraphButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if self.currentAccount() == nil {
            // We check to see if we have a current logged in account.
            // If we don't, then we need to sign someone in.
            self.acquireTokenInteractively()
        } else {
            self.acquireTokenSilently()
        }
    }

    func getContentWithToken() {

        // Specify the Graph API endpoint
        let url = URL(string: kGraphURI)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        // Set the Authorization header for the request. We use Bearer tokens, so we specify Bearer + the token we got from the result
        request.setValue("Bearer \(self.accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            if let error = error {
                self.loggingText.text = "Couldn't get graph result: \(error)"
                return
            }

            guard let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) else {

                self.loggingText.text =  "Couldn't deserialize result JSON"
                return
            }

            self.loggingText.text = "Result from Graph: \(result))"

            }.resume()
    }

    func acquireTokenInteractively() {

        guard let applicationContext = self.applicationContext else { return }

        applicationContext.acquireToken(forScopes: ApplicationConstants.kScopes) { (result, error) in

            if let error = error {
                self.loggingText.text = "Could not acquire token: \(error)"
                return
            }

            guard let result = result else {

                self.loggingText.text = "Could not acquire token: No result returned"
                return
            }

            self.accessToken = result.accessToken
            self.loggingText.text = "Access token is \(self.accessToken)"
            self.signoutButton.isEnabled = true
            self.getContentWithToken()
        }
    }

    func acquireTokenSilently() {

        guard let applicationContext = self.applicationContext else { return }

        /**
         Acquire a token for an existing account silently
         - forScopes:           Permissions you want included in the access token received
         in the result in the completionBlock. Not all scopes are
         guaranteed to be included in the access token returned.
         - account:             An account object that we retrieved from the application object before that the
         authentication flow will be locked down to.
         - completionBlock:     The completion block that will be called when the authentication
         flow completes, or encounters an error.
         */

        applicationContext.acquireTokenSilent(forScopes: ApplicationConstants.kScopes, account: self.currentAccount()!) { (result, error) in

            if let error = error {

                let nsError = error as NSError

                // interactionRequired means we need to ask the user to sign-in. This usually happens
                // when the user's Refresh Token is expired or if the user has changed their password
                // among other possible reasons.
                if (nsError.domain == MSALErrorDomain
                    && nsError.code == MSALErrorCode.interactionRequired.rawValue) {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.acquireTokenInteractively()
                    }

                } else {
                    self.loggingText.text = "Could not acquire token silently: \(error)"
                }

                return
            }

            guard let result = result else {

                self.loggingText.text = "Could not acquire token: No result returned"
                return
            }

            self.accessToken = result.accessToken
            self.loggingText.text = "Refreshed Access token is \(self.accessToken)"
            self.signoutButton.isEnabled = true
            self.getContentWithToken()
        }
    }

    func currentAccount() -> MSALAccount? {

        guard let applicationContext = self.applicationContext else { return nil }

        // We retrieve our current account by getting the first account from cache
        // In multi-account applications, account should be retrieved by home account identifier or username instead
        do {

            let cachedAccounts = try applicationContext.allAccounts()

            if !cachedAccounts.isEmpty {
                return cachedAccounts.first
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {

            self.loggingText.text = "Didn't find any accounts in cache: \(error)"
        }

        return nil
    }

}

//

struct ApplicationConstants {
    static let ResourceId  = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    static let kAuthority  = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0"
    static let kGraphURI   = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"
    static let kScopes     = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite",
                              "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send",
                              "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite",
                              "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All"]
    static var kClientID = "6d5a8e6d-0281-4003-8feb-43a9ca39d4d2"

    enum MSGraphError: Error {
        case nsErrorType(error: NSError)
    }
}
```

Comment: The [error code](https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-34018) indicates that you haven't correctly added the adalcache keychain sharing item

Comment: This problem is also referenced specifically here https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/wiki/Keychain-on-iOS

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Comment: As well as enabling keychain sharing, did you add `com.microsoft.adalcache` as a keychain identifier?

Comment: @Paulw11 that fixed it.. couldn't see that part of configuration on any of the steps in the documentation available! Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ensure you have added the correct identifier to your keychain sharing group. The default value is `com.microsoft.adalcache`.